# How is it that Borel sets of $\mathbb{C}$ equal the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> **2.5 Corollary**. A function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is $\mathcal{M}$ -measurable iff $\operatorname{Re} f$ and
> $\operatorname{Im} f$ are $\mathcal{M}$-measurable.
>
> Proof. This follows since
> $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}=\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}
>  \otimes \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ by Proposition $1.5 .$

In Corollary 2.5, why are we allowed to say that $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}$? How could a set of complex numbers be in $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$? Is this a different notion of equality used here?

> The following are referenced propositions:
>
> [image]

Comment: Did you mean Borel when you typed *bore* and *boreal* in the title?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks! I typed that on an iPad

Comment: "Boreal" could be interesting, too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more substantive assertion is not really about real versus complex numbers, but, for example, that a function $f(x)=(f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)):X\to \mathbb R^n$ is measurable if and only if each of the component functions $f_j$ is measurable. (Where each of these maps $X\to\mathbb R$, as suggested by the notation.)

This follows by the same argument as in your cited source.

The specific relevance to complex-valued functions is via the identification of $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2$ by $x+iy\to \mathbb R^2$, which is a homeomorphism. Since it's a homeomorphism, it will map Borel sets in the one to the Borel sets in the other...

Answer (score 4):

As metric spaces, $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$ are isomorphic (via $a+bi\mapsto(a,b)$). If we denote the isomorphism by $\varphi:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R^2$, then the corollary really says $\mathcal B_{\mathbb C}=\{\varphi(S)|S\in\mathcal B_{\mathbb R^2}\}$.

But such isomorphisms (surjective isometries? I don't know of a better name) preserve properties of metric spaces, so usually isomorphic things are identified (as an abuse of notation).

Comment: Hmm, I know not everything is preserved via isomorphisms (Like boundedness, etc.).  I wonder if anything is not preserved under isometric isomorphisms between metric spaces?

Comment: I meant isometric isomorphism in this answer. What do you mean exactly by (non-isometric) isomorphisms of metric spaces?

Comment: Bleh, I meant homeomorphisms (That preserve topology but not everything), not isometries.

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case boundedness, completeness, etc. won't be preserved. On the other hand isometric isomorphisms should be good enough for metric spaces.

Comment: You can say more: $\mathbb C$ is exactly equal to $\mathbb R^2$ as sets.

Comment: @zhw. I would be careful with that. $\mathbb C$ could just as well be defined as a quotient ring of the polynomial ring over $\mathbb R$, which, using the usual construction, looks nothing like $\mathbb R^2$ as a set.